# udev rules to assign/restrict serial ports to a range of numbers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev, serial-port

I'm trying to segregate serial ports based on the manufacturer attribute `ATTRS{manufacturer}`.

I would like to assign `/dev/ttyUSBx` to those detected as from manufacturer A, where `x` can take a value between `0` and `9` only. Similarly, for those detected as from manufacturer B, I want to assign `/dev/ttyUSBy`, where `y` can take a value between `10` and `19` only.

I happened to come across [this](https://txlab.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/udev-rules-for-ttyusb-devices/) article, where the author says its possible to modify the names using `symlinks`. Can we do something like that to meet my requirement?

Comment: It might be difficult to change the name/number of the device, as that is creaqted by the kernel. But you can make symlinks based on the vendor, and named after the vendor, by using udev rules.

Comment: There are some examples [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105144/udev-rule-for-assigning-known-symlinks-for-identical-usb-serial-devices), using external programs/scripts for numbering.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you might check

```
$ ls -l /dev/serial/by-id/
```

(after plugged in at least one usb-serial adapter) to check if this gives you an idea to solve your problem.

You could also check `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules` to have an example and see how `/dev/serial` works. On my Kubuntu 16.04 it looks like this:

```
ACTION=="remove", GOTO="serial_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="tty", GOTO="serial_end"

SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", ENV{ID_BUS}="pci", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}="$attr{vendor}", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}="$attr{device}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", IMPORT{builtin}="hwdb --subsystem=pci"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id", IMPORT{builtin}="hwdb --subsystem=usb"

# /dev/serial/by-path/, /dev/serial/by-id/ for USB devices
KERNEL!="ttyUSB[0-9]*|ttyACM[0-9]*", GOTO="serial_end"

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial", ENV{.ID_PORT}="$attr{port_number}"

IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"
ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", ENV{.ID_PORT}=="", SYMLINK+="serial/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}"
ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", ENV{.ID_PORT}=="?*", SYMLINK+="serial/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-port$env{.ID_PORT}"

IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="", GOTO="serial_end"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}="$attr{bInterfaceNumber}"
ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="", GOTO="serial_end"
ENV{.ID_PORT}=="", SYMLINK+="serial/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-if$env{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}"
ENV{.ID_PORT}=="?*", SYMLINK+="serial/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-if$env{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}-port$env{.ID_PORT}"

LABEL="serial_end"
```